# Rank on multiple columns in Oracle 19C

Tags: oracle, rank, oracle19c, ranking-functions, oracle-analytics

Could you please suggest a simple way to calculate rank on multiple columns in Oracle 19c.

```
For instance - considering [ Mango | 1 | 1 ] group from the table

NAME    DAY PROD    S       M       P   AMT1    AMT2    AMT3
----------------------------------------------------------
MANGO   1   1       -2.75   3       15  21.277  80      80
MANGO   1   1       -2.75   1.5     21  27.778  80      80
MANGO   1   1       -2.75   3       21  27.778  80      80
MANGO   1   1       -2.75   3       14  20      80      80

Expected output : 2nd row
```

For each group [NAME, DAY, PROD], I need to identify a row which has **min[abs(S)]** value.
If this returns multiple rows with same values [NAME, DAY, PROD, S], then next column to be considered is row having **max(AMT1)**.
Again in case of more than one row is fetched with same [NAME, DAY, PROD, S, AMT1], next factor to be considered is **min(M)**.
Lastly, **min(P)**.

Overall, a single row should be returned for each group [NAME, DAY, PROD]
considering order for ranking rows as **min(abs(S)) -> max(AMT1) -> min(M) -> min(P)**

**Expected Output for sample Records** : Provided SQLs in [DB_Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ff569/1)

```
NAME    DAY PROD    S       M   P   AMT1    AMT2    AMT3                final deciding factor
----------------------------------------------------------
APPLE   1   1       -2.5    3   21  27.778  80      80          --->    min(abs(S))
APPLE   8   0.5     -1.25   3   10  51.02   90      90          --->    max(AMT1)
MANGO   5   1       -1.75   3   14  24      83.333  83.333      --->    min(P)
MANGO   1   1       -2.75   1.5 21  27.778  80      80          --->    min(M)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY name, day, prod
           ORDER BY ABS(s) ASC,
                    amt1   DESC,
                    m      ASC,
                    p      ASC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   test3 t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | NAME | DAY | PROD | S | M | P | AMT1 | AMT2 | AMT3 | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | APPLE | 1 | 1 | -2.5 | 3 | 21 | 27.778 | 80 | 80 | 1 |
> | APPLE | 8 | .5 | -1.25 | 3 | 10 | 51.02 | 90 | 90 | 1 |
> | MANGO | 1 | 1 | -2.75 | 1.5 | 21 | 27.778 | 80 | 801 |  |
> | MANGO | 5 | 1 | -1.75 | 3 | 14 | 24 | 83.333 | 83.333 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efabbb31c168641916d04056e8139562)*